# How do I change the width of an image logo while moving it to the far left?

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and have been struggling quite a bit. Basically I have an image logo on my navbar but it is too big so I add a width and a margin-right:auto to move it to the far left along with a flex-end to the header. However if I add the width then the object does not move. Is there any workaround that does not require me to modify the image size in photoshop and save it again? Thanks`

```css
header{
    width:100%;
    height:13vh;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding:30px 10%;
}

.logo{
    margin-right:auto;
    width:140px;
    cursor:pointer;

}


.nav-links li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;

}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="logo" src="images/favicon.png">

    </a>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shipping</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a class="cta" href="#">Get a Quote</a>
</header>
```

Comment: can you provide the HTML code ?

Comment: @Pain added HTML for reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You acn modify the width of the `<a>` wrapping the `<img>` and set image width to 100%

Note: you have too much padding around the header. you should remove it, if its not needed, and to get rid of the scrollbars use this [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) its really useful.

Try this

```css
header{
  width:100%;
  height:13vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding:30px 10%;
}

header a.logo-link {
  width: 60px; /* I set it to 60px just make it look nice */
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo{
  width:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.nav-links li{
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <a class="logo-link" href="#">
            <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Mangekyou_Sharingan_Itachi.svg/768px-Mangekyou_Sharingan_Itachi.svg.png">
        </a>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shipping</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="cta" href="#">Get a Quote</a>
    </header>
```

Comment: I think I am understanding it a little better could I also just do .logo-link? instead of referencing the header and a class? Also I noticed that the auto margin causes a space in between the links and the logo. To rectify this would I just make another div class that holds the nav links and the logo and auto margin that div? Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. Yes you can do `.logo-link` & 2. You can just remove `margin-right: auto`